# Would it be a good idea to AJAX to load page content?

Tags: php, ajax, dynamic

Basically, lets say for the index.html page of a website, instead of using php to load the middle section( content between header and footer ) of the webpage?

Comment: I have a site like that. While it works, it turns out to be annoying most of the time. Pretty much only done it for laziness. (Which is: not a good reason.)

Comment: if it's a homepage, then rather not (because it doesn't change that often)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may come across a situation that this is good for.  For instance, if your "page" is really a rather heavy-weight client-side web application, then perhaps this is the right choice.  Generally though, this is a terrible idea.

What harm do you have in generating a page already filled with your content?  You avoid compatibility issues, SEO issues, it loads quickly, and that's one less HTTP request to your server.  Just because "good JS frameworks that incorporate this philosophy" exists doesn't mean it is the right method for your application.

Each site is different, but the default answer should be certainly not.  If the conditions are right, then yes.  Base this decision on what is best for your users.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Many frameworks are moving in this direction, and most consumer sites (Facebook, Twitter) load most of the content after the main page is loaded.

Provided your users have JS enabled browsers, the AJAX load improves user experience by providing a faster response time and a more dynamic interface for the content which is likely to change.  If done correctly, it will actually improve the maintainability of your application by carrying data organization and presentation methodologies through your front-end.

If you want to dive all the way in there are good JS frameworks that incorporate this philosophy into your design, [Sproutcore](http://www.sproutcore.com/) and [Backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) are both worth looking into.

**Edit**

I'm building web applications now, so I read questions with that slant.  If, as people have pointed out, you're just building brochureware webpages then you won't see a real benefit from AJAX content loads and will hurt your SEO.

Comment: Faster response time?  Are you crazy?  Better just to load the page with the content rather than to have to execute some JS and then make another request, don't you think?

Comment: I'm not crazy, I'm right.  The total load time for the page is less important than the time that elapses before the user gets feedback.  That's why are 'Loading...' animations are worth downloading an extra gif and executing extra javascript.

Comment: is there any research available to back this up?  Web application or not, the only time I don't mind seeing those 500 byte GIFs are when they indicate something I didn't already know... such as the page loading data *after* I am in the application, not on initial load.  I am probably not *most users* though, and would like to see some research on this if you know of any.

Answer (score 0):

If you assume that each of your visitors has AJAX-enabled browser (by which I mean JS turned on, etc.), then that would be pretty much correct. I'm not sure (source code looks like), but this seems to be the way Facebook loads it's middle section.

Of course you will have to use PHP either, I hope you know.

Comment: well i would only need to use php for receiving and responding to the AJAX server calls right?

Comment: PHP would only respond to AJAX request coming from user's browser. I wouldn't really call it a server call.

Comment: UMM..i think your wrong, it is a server call b/c it's the server that is serving the pages and facilitator between the technologies on the server, and PHP happens to be one of those technologies.

Comment: It's just the matter of naming, most people call it *request* rather than call. If someone says 'server call', what I think of is more like SOAP or RPC than AJAX and PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If Search Engine Optimization is a concern for the project the answer is NO =)

Search engines generally only fetch the source code for each page.